# Updating an interrupted checked-out repository with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out a repository, and during the download the checkout was interrupted (for unknown reasons; the download dialog just froze up after about 30 minutes).  I'd like to "finish" the checkout without having to re-download all the files that were successful.  Trying "update to revision" results in an error about the working copy being locked.  Attempting to clear the lock says that no lock is in place.

I'm using the most recent version of TortoiseSVN (downloaded today).  I'm unfamiliar with this software specifically and subversion in general (toyed with it years ago, and reinstalled today in order to access another developer's source).

TYIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lock in this case does not refer to a SVN lock, but to an internal lock file. SVN Cleanup fixes that.

In case SVN Cleanup does not work you may have better luck by deleting the last folder downloaded. That sometimes helped in SVN 1.6, but with the new WC format in SVN 1.7 (as in the latest TortoiseSVN) I'm not sure if that helps anymore.

Comment: that did it - thank you.  note for anyone else who reads this - i had to run cleanup on the root - trying to cleanup branches gave the same locked error

Answer (score 2):

You need use cleanUp command before update command